# UIView CGAffineTransform scale issue (autolayout issue?)

Tags: ios, autolayout, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform, cgaffinetransformscale

I am trying to apply a simple `CGAffineTransform` to an imageView by scaling to 0, but for some reason the frame of the imageView is getting screwed up just before the animation starts. It appears as though autolayout is applying to the shrunken view. I don't want that at all. I want the view to remain "relatively" where it was and just visually shrink to its center, but because the view is tied to the top and right of its containing view, it is being moved.

What I want is for it to shrink into its center and disappear, but just before it starts, the frame of the imageView is jumping to the top-right of its container (it seems as though iOS is calculating its size after the animation and using that to reposition it before the animation starts). After it jumps there, the animation works properly with respect to itself, with the view shrinking relative to its center, but I want to avoid it moving in the first place.

This is all taking place inside a `UITableViewCell` that is managed by autolayout, so I'm guessing this has something to do with autolayout and `<understatement>` would not be the first time autolayout has gotten in my way `</understatement>`.

Is there any way to prevent autolayout from affecting the transform?

Comment: Looks like it is indeed autolayout causing problems again: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14105757/238948

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15607895/604375