# CGAffineTransformRotate doesn't work like expect

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation

My code like follow

```
self.view1.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.view1.transform,M_PI/2);
self.view1.transform = transform;
```

My UI is like follow

[image]

The light green background view is view1,it has a subview a label.If i run the code, in my opinion the view and the label will rotated M_PI/2 around the progressview's left point.But the truth is like follow:

[image]

Comment: I cann't see light green background view?

Comment: I think your view 1 might not be what you think.  Is it defined in a storyboard?  Are you sure you have view1 linked to the view, or is it just linked to the label?

Comment: @iMani sorry the cyan background color view is view1

Comment: @HalR sorry the cyan background color view is view1

Comment: Check if you have any autolayout constraint. I have seen that the behavior is different and unpredictable with some constraints. To be sure, debug disabling autolayout and removing all the autosizing masks

Comment: @LombaX yes, you are right. How can i do it with autolayout?

Comment: Check this post ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943107/how-do-i-adjust-the-anchor-point-of-a-calayer-when-auto-layout-is-being-used/14105757#14105757

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.view1);
```

To check that self.view1 - is a background view, not the label.
Also I think you need to change anchorPoint.

Comment: I'm sorry the cyan backgroundcolor view is view1

Comment: This is more a comment asking for clarification, than it is an answer

Comment: @Dracuuula I expect so. It is your code :)