# Why is my view moving before animating?

Tags: objective-c

I am scaling a view so that it grows. It is scaling correctly but the view is moving to the right before animating. I'm not sure what is causing it and more importantly how to fix it.

Here's my code:

(.H file)
[image]

(.M file) I have my custom Method
[image]

(.M file) I have the call to the method
[image]

Here's what the view looks like before and after animation...
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try calling `[super viewDidAppear:animated];`

Comment: Please take the advice given to you in your previous question. When overriding any life cycle method in a UIViewController or any of its subclasses, you should **always** call the method's super implementation.

Comment: I didn't read your response until after I posted this. I think you're right. I'm gonna try to put the view as a subview as you suggested.

Comment: Problem solved. I added the view as a subview and then set the leading and trailing constraints. Thanks.

Comment: Problem solved. I added the view as a subview and then set the leading and trailing constraints. Thanks.

Comment: Do not ask the same question twice (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994862/why-is-my-uiview-not-growing-with-cgaffinetransformmakescale)

Comment: Vote to close on the grounds that you are duplicating yourself, downvoted because you are not listening to the answers that you get.