# UIDynamics and Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uikit-dynamics

Recently I used UIDynamics to animate an image view into place. However, because its autolayout y-pos constraint was set to off-screen, when navigating away from the screen and then returning to it, my image view was being placed off-screen again. The animation took about 3 seconds, so after three seconds I just reset the constraint. That feels a little hacky.

So my question is this: what is the proper way to handle autolayout and UIDynamics at the same time?

Comment: Proper way to handle UIDynamics and AutoLayout? Keep them separate at all costs. You can add dynamics to a view and then INTERNALLY to that view lay it out with auto layout. But don't use them together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not really a dynamics problem. Autolayout is incompatible with *any* view animation, or *any* manual setting of the frame: when layout comes along, it is the *constraints* that will be obeyed. It is up to you, if you move a view manually in *any* way, to update the constraints to match its new position/size/whatever.

Having said that: with UIKit Dynamics, when the animation ends, the animator will pause, and the animator's delegate is notified:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate/dynamicAnimatorDidPause:

So that is the moment to update the constraints.

Comment: *"Autolayout is incompatible with any view animation"*...although, you can animate a view layout that does not incorporate `UIKitDynamics` by updating the autolayout constraints themselves. (Or am I doing something that will bite me later?)

Comment: @AnthonyC What you're doing is perfectly right. The problem is that it doesn't work in all situations. Even outside of UIKit Dynamics, the autolayout constraints on a view not match the aspects of that view that you want to animate. For example, applying a rotation transform to a constrained view is typically a disaster. See my little essay here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14105757/341994

Answer (score 3):

You have a nice solution provided by Geppy Parziale in [this tutorial](http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/78510602190/uikit-dynamics-layer-constraint).

Basically you can create an object that conforms to UIDynamicItem:

```
@interface DynamicHub : NSObject <UIDynamicItem>
    @property(nonatomic, readonly) CGRect bounds;
    @property(nonatomic, readwrite) CGPoint center;
    @property(nonatomic, readwrite) CGAffineTransform transform;
@end
```

That needs to init the bounds or it will crash:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
    return self;
}
```

And then you use UIDynamics on that object and use the intermediate values to update your constraints:

```
DynamicHub *dynamicHub = [[DynamicHub alloc] init];

UISnapBehavior *snapBehavior = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:dynamicHub
                                           snapToPoint:CGPointMake(50.0, 150.0)];
[snapBehavior setDamping:.1];

snapBehavior.action = ^{
     self.firstConstraint.constant = [dynamicHub center].y;
     self.secondConstraint.constant = [dynamicHub center].x;
};

[self.animator addBehavior:snapBehavior];
```

Comment: Why not just use a UIView instead of a DynamicHub?