# Move and resize UILabel with CGAfficeTransform

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

Basically I want to move a UILabel up 20px and resize it to 55% of it's original size.

=> x stays the same, y,height, width decrease.

What I came up is following :

```
//_line a UILabel* 
CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.55f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -20);
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    _line.transform = transform;
}];
```

Unfortunately I don't get the expected result. It (slightly) moves up but also moves to the right.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Have you tried using CGAffineTransformConcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the job fob me : a second translation

```
CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.55f;
CGFloat x_delta = _line.frame.size.width * (1-scaleFactor);
CGFloat y_delta = _line.frame.size.height * (1-scaleFactor);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -20);
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -x_delta, -y_delta);
    _line.transform = transform;
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're overwriting the transform. You initially set `transform` to the translation transformation, and then before anything has happened you reset it to the scale transformation. So all it's doing is the scale action.

Instead you need to combine the two matrices and store their combination into `transform`. Try this:

```
CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.55f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    CGAffineTransform translationTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -20);
    CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    CGAffineTransform totalTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translationTransform, scaleTransform);
    _line.transform = totalTransform;
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using Auto Layout. Auto Layout and view transforms are enemies of one another. You perform the transform, but then Auto Layout kicks in and changes the frame of the label essentially back to what it was.

Comment: See my rant on this topic here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_autolayout_and_view_transforms

Comment: And I give several workarounds in detail in this Stack Overflow "essay": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943107/how-do-i-adjust-the-anchor-point-of-a-calayer-when-auto-layout-is-being-used/14105757#14105757

Comment: Nope, I disabled autolayout.