# Rotate UI Elements programmatically after shouldAutorotate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autorotate

I have a `viewController` that should not "autorotate", but manually rotate specific GUI elements. The reason is that I use the front camera for taking a picture and I don't want the `UIView` that contains my `UIImageView` to be rotated. 
My code looks like this:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    [self performSelector:@selector(refreshView) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    return NO; // don't autorotate!
}
```

and:

```
- (void) refreshView  {
    UIDeviceOrientation actualDeviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    float    rotation        = 0;    // UIDeviceOrientationPortrait
    if      (actualDeviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)  rotation = 180;
    else if (actualDeviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)       rotation = 90;
    else if (actualDeviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)      rotation = 270;
    float    rotationRadians = rotation * M_PI / 180;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                 animations:^(void) {
                     self.labelPrize.center        = self.prizeView.center;
                     self.prizeView.transform      = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationRadians);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished){  }];
}
```

"labelPrize" is the label with the caption "20 EURO" that is seen on the screenshots below, "prizeView" is it's container. **prizeView is the only GUI element that has constraints defined**, which look like this:

[image: Properties of prizeView]

Just for clarification, here's what **"labelPrize"** looks like:

[image: Properties of labelPrize]

And finally, here's what the app produces:

[image]

This is not what I want to achieve, I'd like "prizeView"/"labelPrize" to be

- always aligned to the horizon
- always in the exact center of the screen

Also worth mentioning: I'd like to add labels above (header) and a button below ("okay") my "labelPrize" and rotate/position them as well in `refreshView()`.

**Thanks for any help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two big problems here. Let's take them one at a time.

**(1)**

```
self.labelPrize.center = self.prizeView.center;
```

Think about it. `labelPrize` is a subview of `prizeView`. So you are mixing apples with oranges as far as coordinate systems go: `labelPrize.center` is measured with respect to `prizeView.bounds`, but `prizeView.center` is measured with respect to `self.view.bounds`. To keep the center of `labelPrize` at the center of `prizeView`, position it at the midpoint of `prizeView`'s bounds. (However, you should not have to move it at all because the transform transforms the bounds.)

**(2)**

Rotation view transforms and auto layout are deadly enemies, as I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14105757/341994). That is why rotating the transform of `prizeView` seems to shift its position as well. My answer there gives you several possible workarounds.