# Temporarily remove NSLayoutConstraint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass laid out using AutoLayout, and I’d like a small animation in which the image view transforms, grows a bit and shrinks back.

At present, due to the constraints, the labels on the right side of the image are moving too (as they should be).

I’d like a quick and easy means to temporarily say “leave those labels where they currently are while this animation is running”. Is that something I can do without needing to remove and re-add those constraints, which is a lot of hassle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API to say "leave these views here", temporarily disabling some parts of the autolayout. There are several possible solutions:

- remove your constraints during animation
- arrange your constraints differently (making them to a superview of the image view, for example, or having them only depend on the center of the image view)
- override layoutSubviews of a container view to stick your labels back where you want them after autolayout runs in `[super layoutSubviews]` (or remove the transform of your image view, run autolayout and then put it back)
- subclass your image view and override `frameForAlignmentRect:` and `alignmentRectForFrame:` to get autolayout to use the untransformed frame for alignment purposes.

More details and suggestions are available in the answers here, which is a similar question of how to make transforms and autolayout play together: [How do I adjust the anchor point of a CALayer, when Auto Layout is being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943107/how-do-i-adjust-the-anchor-point-of-a-calayer-when-auto-layout-is-being-used/14105757#14105757)

Comment: This is a great answer, but thankfully I didn’t need it. I used a `CABasicAnimation` in place of a UIView animation, since those don’t trigger layout changes.

Comment: @lukech That is one option, but be careful, as if anything else causes a layout during your animation, you'll be back to the same bug you started with.

Answer (score 6):

Starting in iOS 8 `NSLayoutConstraints` now have an `active` property that you can change `myConstraint.active = NO;`. This removes the constraint, while setting this value to `YES` will [re]add it:

> Activating or deactivating the constraint calls addConstraint: and
>   removeConstraint: on the view that is the closest common ancestor of
>   the items managed by this constraint. Use this property instead of
>   calling addConstraint: or removeConstraint: directly.
>   [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/active)

Additionally, there are two new class methods `activateConstraints:` and `deactivateConstraints:` that take an array of constraints (`NSArray<NSLayoutConstraint>`), so that can be helpful, especially if you have an `IBOutletCollection` with constraints.

`[NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:myConstraints];`