# Changing view transform changes views positions on iOS 7 but not on ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

I have a container view controller. It adds another controller as child view controller, and its view to view hierarchy.

So now I have:

```
UIView *self.view //main view
UIView *childView //child view controller's view
```

I also have `UIImageView *imageView` as child to `childView`. ImageView is pinned with constraints to its parent from left, right and top with some constant (12 points).

When I tap the button I slide the child view with the following code:

```
- (void)swipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized && !self.menuOpened) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

            self.childView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0, 120);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }
}
```

So the issue - right before the animation starts, the `imageView` moves its position up some amount.
This can be countered by changing the constraint to some arbitary amount right before and after animation, but this is a dirty hack since it requires different values for different devices.

What it should look like and actually works on ios 8:

[image]

What it looks like on iOS 7 (the settings label is irrelevant, notice the position of image in relation to nav bar):

[image]

Again, on iOS 8 the transform works as it should, none of the subviews are moved. On iOS 7 subviews move out of control when view transform changes. How do I fix that?

Comment: Well, `AutoLayout` does not work with `CGAffineTransform`. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943107/how-do-i-adjust-the-anchor-point-of-a-calayer-when-auto-layout-is-being-used/14105757#14105757

Comment: @BartekChlebek Bartek could you make an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, AutoLayout does not work with CGAffineTransform. Have a look at this [How do I adjust the anchor point of a CALayer, when Auto Layout is being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943107/how-do-i-adjust-the-anchor-point-of-a-calayer-when-auto-layout-is-being-used/14105757#14105757)

Comment: It works but not well. Indeed using a layer transform is better. I recommend you this link rather than the one proposed. http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_autolayout_and_view_transforms.