# iOS 8 works fine, iOS 7 gets Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints due to view transform affecting layout constraints

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, autolayout, uikit

I'm working on a project which we've been testing on iOS 8 devices for a few weeks. Today I've decided to test it on iOS 7.1 Simulator and my app logged the infamous constraints error:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't
understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
```

I know about auto layout, and it's near impossible to demonstrate a sample (I'd need to put almost the whole project here as there are many views that do custom drawing, many constraints related to other views etc) here. On iOS 8 everything draws perfectly. On iOS 7, some of my views just have zero width/height (debugged them) while some others with *related width/height to those views* draw perfectly. One thing I know is that I've double checked that **there are no constraints involving container margins**. I know it's new in iOS 8. Why could be another reason? Here is the full trace if it helps:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a0e86b0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7a17dfe0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7a0e7a40 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a0e86e0 H:[UIView:0x7a17dfe0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7a0e7a40 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x79ecc850 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x7a0e7a40(320)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a00add0 h=-&- v=-&- UITransitionView:0x79f9c110.width == UILayoutContainerView:0x79f9c070.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a00a550 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x79f9c070.width == UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7a1b0340.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a009840 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7a1b0340.width == UINavigationTransitionView:0x7a18cfd0.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a008cc0 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0x7a18cfd0.width == UILayoutContainerView:0x7a0f17b0.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a008160 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x7a0f17b0.width == UIView:0x7a17dfe0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cdcc000 MyAppMoodTypeSelectionView:0x7f19ddf0.width == 2.5*MyAppFaceView:0x7f19e8b0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cde0380 MyAppMoodTypeSelectionView:0x7f19ddf0.width == 0.75*UIView:0x7cddfcf0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cde0470 MyAppRoundView:0x7a005e00.width == MyAppFaceView:0x7f19e8b0.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f1a0a20 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x7cddfcf0.width == UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7cde15c0.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f1a10d0 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7cde15c0.width == UINavigationTransitionView:0x7cdd93a0.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f1a1750 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0x7cdd93a0.width == UILayoutContainerView:0x7a053c60.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f1a1e90 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x7a053c60.width == UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7cdddc10.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f1a25e0 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7cdddc10.width == UITransitionView:0x79f9c110.width>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cdcc000 MyAppMoodTypeSelectionView:0x7f19ddf0.width == 2.5*MyAppFaceView:0x7f19e8b0.width>
```

The very same app works perfectly fine with all the constraints correct and satisfied on iOS 8.1, both on device and simulator. On iOS 7.1, I'm getting these error even **on same screen sizes.**

I've tried turning `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` off on all views (expect the main container view, otherwise the screen goes black).

What would be the reason? What exactly did change from iOS 7 to iOS 8 in regards to auto layout other than the new container margin constraints?

**UPDATE:** I have transform-changing code in my class. Apparently, on iOS 8, the layout constraints are not affected by the transform but on iOS 7, they *are* affected by the transform. Still looking for a solution though, without hard-coding values.

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14105757/792677) answer interesting.

Comment: @A-Live I was just looking at that one right now :)

Answer (score -3):

```
cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds
```