# Subviews Misplaced after superview is scaled via CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, autolayout, cgaffinetransformscale

I am trying to Scale a UiView and its UIImageView subview using:
        `CGAffineTransform original = mv.transform;
        CGAffineTransform new = CGAffineTransformScale(original, 2, 2);`

But this results in the ImageView being way off from where it started:

[image: Before the transofrm the imageview (the book) is at the center of the purple circle. This shows it after the transform(which is done in a spring animation block)]

Before the transofrm the imageview (the book) is at the center of the purple circle. This shows it after the transform(which is done in a spring animation block)

For the record autolayout is off in IB

Comment: @Andy I did use autolayout to center the imageview but even if i remove the constraints before carrying out the transform the issue remains

Comment: I still believe it's autolayout messing with you. Have you considered using CALayer/CAShapeLayer? I know it's extra work to center them, but it worth a shot. I had similar behavior on autolayout until I turned it off with translatesAutosizingMaskTo... There is a quite comprehensive research on that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943107/how-do-i-adjust-the-anchor-point-of-a-calayer-when-auto-layout-is-being-used?lq=1

Comment: I tried this with the subview being centered in the larger view with auto layout (centerX and centerY). It worked fine. Are you sure your "book" is a subview of the purple circle?

Comment: @Andy Yup,  Its definitely autolayout. I didnt add any constraints and set the view by using its frame property and it worked just fine.

Comment: @rdelmar Did you also set the views height and width constraints when you set centerX and centerY contraints? I have added centerX, centerY and height and width constraints to the imageview.

Comment: Yes, I did. Both views had fixed height and width.

Answer (score 1):

So after tinkering with it for some hours, I was able produce the desired effect. I was also changing the center of the view in the animation block and I found that if I placed the statement assigning the center value **before**  assigned the new transfrom, the subview stayed centered during the transform and center - change. Also, I found that if I was working with a UIView subclass, I had to make a call to `layoutIfNeeded` before the animation block on the view being scaled and moved. Interestingly enough, when working with regular UIView objects I found that it was not necessary to make the call to `layoutIfNeeded` in order to produce the desired effect of keeping the subview centered after the center cahnge and transform.

I am at a loss as to why these specific conditions are required to keep the subview centered during a transform and coordinate move. I've been looking through the Apple Documentation but have yet to find a sure explanation.