# Animating with UIDynamicAnimator when Autolayout is in play

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uidynamicanimator

I have a ViewController that has been configured in InterfaceBuilder to use AutoLayout for all of its subviews. Layout is working fine.

I want to make one of the subviews bounce using the cool gravity effects provided by UIDynamicAnimator. I didn't think that would work with AutoLayout, but I tried it and it does. It works quite well!

**My question is**, is this the expected behavior? Is it going to cause problems somewhere? Does Apple provide any guidance around combining AutoLayout and UIDynamicAnimators?

Here is the code, for anyone interested:

```
    var boundaryFrame = self.buttonBackgroundView.frame
    boundaryFrame = CGRect(x: 0,
        y: boundaryFrame.origin.y + (boundaryFrame.height + 1),
        width: self.view.frame.width,
        height: 2)

    self.animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)
    var gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [self.buttonBackgroundView])
    gravity.magnitude = 0.5

    var collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [self.buttonBackgroundView])
    var boundaryId: NSMutableString = NSMutableString(string: "bottomBoundary")
    let boundaryPath = UIBezierPath(rect: boundaryFrame)
    collision.addBoundaryWithIdentifier(boundaryId, forPath: boundaryPath)

    let bounceProperties = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [self.buttonBackgroundView])
    bounceProperties.elasticity = 0.5

    // Move it up before causing it to bounce down to its original location
    self.setMeUpTopConstraint.constant = 10
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    // Start animating
    animator.addBehavior(gravity)
    animator.addBehavior(collision)
    animator.addBehavior(bounceProperties)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is, is this the expected behavior? Is it going to cause problems somewhere? Does Apple provide any guidance around combining AutoLayout and UIDynamicAnimators?

Basically, UIKit Dynamics does *not* play well with auto layout. Basically the rule is that changing the frame / center of something is contrary to auto layout - and that is exactly what UIKit Dynamics does. The only reason you are not encountering a problem is that, by chance, layout does not happen to be occurring on the view(s) you are animating.

The way to test is this. Run your code, and then (when the animation has finished; possibly you'll need to be using delayed performance) run

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded
```

That causes layout to happen. If things jump around at that moment, it exposes the issue.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. In this case I'm animating something back into its final layout, and no other layout changes occur during the animation, so maybe it's okay to use in this scenario. 3 questions for you: 1. Are you saying that if layout were to occur during animation, that that would cause problems? 2. Never heard of "delayed performance" before, but Google shows me it's a thing. Can you point me to any resources about it? 3. What would you do if you wanted to animate (say, bounce or wiggle) a UI element in a viewcontroller that is using autolayout?

Comment: @skypecakes 1. Yes - or if occurred afterwards. But if your animation returns everything to exactly its original position, you won't see a problem, because what you did (with frames) and what auto layout will do (with constraints) have the same result. 2. See my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html#_delayed_performance 3.Big subject, but see my essay here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943107/how-do-i-adjust-the-anchor-point-of-a-calayer-when-auto-layout-is-being-used/14105757#14105757

Comment: Thanks again. I'm reading your discussion of delayed performance now. Regarding #1 and #3, I must admit I don't know enough about animation in iOS to understand your essay, or even how I'm using frames in my animation! I'd love to do a deep-dive, spend enough time to understand it well. How did you learn so much about animation? Got any advice for someone starting out?

Comment: @skypecakes Everything I know, I know from reading (and writing) my own book. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, UIDynamicAnimator works fine with AutoLayout. I have an app that relies heavily on UIDynamicAnimator and uses constraints, and it has worked fine. The only issue I have found is that UIView animateWithDuration doesn't work with constraints, but that method doesn't work well with UIDynamicAnimator anyways.
Hope it helps :)