# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation iOS 7 frame change bug fix

Tags: swift, ios7

`CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()` generates on iOS 7 a weird bug when trying to rotate an object (label, button, etc.) to an angle different than 90, 180, 360, etc.

From iOS 8 and onwards the bug is gone.

The fix is in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to this bug is to apply a `CABasicAnimation` on the **layer**, not a `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`on the **view** of the button.

For some reason when you apply it on the view, it messes with the frame and AutoLayout. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943107/how-do-i-adjust-the-anchor-point-of-a-calayer-when-auto-layout-is-being-used/14105757#14105757).

Here's how to implement this fix:

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
animation.autoreverses = false
animation.duration = 0.3
animation.fromValue = 0
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
animation.removedOnCompletion = false
animation.toValue = 3.14/4    // 45 degrees
self.myButton.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "45rotation")
```